# Extracting peer Information from a torrent file

Tags: python, p2p, bittorrent

I am implementing a distributed p2p based model in python using python-bittorent library. So, basically i want the peer info/list from a torrent.

```
from bittorrent import Tracker, Torrent
import torrent
import tracker


f=open("0F605C725275D1045361A17B0222B57232EE77BD.torrent","r+")

tor=Torrent(f.name)
tor.get_peers(peer_list)
```

So, I'm wondering what should be the possible way I enter data in peer_list. I mean how am i supposed to enter data like 172.16.44.207:22592, 115.187.33.86:22592, in the form of a list.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You can't extract peer list from a torrent file, because torrent files do not contain a list of peers, only a list of trackers. Peers must be retrieved from the trackers listed in the torrent file. You could use the internal functions defined in the `torrent` module of `python-bittorrent` to make such a request, but `python-bittorrent` doesn't seem to provide a good API for making such single requests to trackers.

Comment: @lanzz what do you suggest using then?

Comment: I don't think it is unsuitable because I've got a better suggestion, but because I've examined its source especially for your specific case, and I've come to this conclusion. You will need to do your own research for a module better suited to your needs.